# Is Ksp measured for covalent compounds as well?

Tags: equilibrium

A quick search on Google tells me that it is only used for ionic compounds but I think it should be used for some covalent compounds given that some of the covalent compounds also dissociate into ions when they dissolve (like most acids)

Comment: You can use it because there is always a mix of characteristics. Only that it will be extremely small.

Comment: It can be used with any equilibrium process.

Comment: Ksp is an equilibrium constant assuming that the dissolved compound dissociates completely. For compounds that are only partially dissociated (eg weak acids), it is not applicable. In those cases a total observed solubility at a specific pH is necessarily used instead.